# Results of direct search and Google Search API not match

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-api, search-engine

I am using the Google Costume Search API. The problem I have is that, I see some inconsistencies between the results of Google API and the results of direct search. For example, when I search for Android from the API, it says:

```
.... 
"request": [
   {
    "title": "Google Custom Search - Android",
    "totalResults": "16600000",
    "searchTerms": "Android",
    "count": 10,
    "startIndex": 1,
    "inputEncoding": "utf8",
    "outputEncoding": "utf8",
    "safe": "off",
    "cx": "013036536707430787589:_pqjad5hr1a"
   }
  ]
 },
...
```

which says "16600000" results. But when I search for Android directly, it gives me "about 1,010,000,000" results. And in some cases this inconsistency is much bigger. What is the reason? Any ideas?

I understand that API and the main search engines might work with different components. But this difference seems to be huge. I am curious if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

I just did the same search, and the total results came out as "877,000,000" which matches neither of the numbers that you provided.

The number of results is an estimate - and very often a very inaccurate one. This is inevitable due to the way inverted indexes are built in search engines. Because of their enormous size, inverted indexes are split into a very large number of buckets. A query only goes "deep" enough into the inverted index to retrieve the first 1000 highest-ranked results that are displayed to a user. Then an estimate is made how many results are in the total index based on the subset that has been retrieved for a query.

Also note that results for most queries are cached using a very wide network of servers. This means that you may get a different estimate of the total number of results based on which server you hit with your query. In other words, two users doing the same search at the same time may see different lists of results with different estimates for the total number of results.